# Delete Issue with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I wrote a simple stored procedure where I'm not able to find the problem in the code

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.BestellDetail_Delete
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @RefId  AS int

AS

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DELETE FROM BestellDetails 
    WHERE       RefBestellId = @RefId

    RETURN
```

C# Code

```
SqlCommand cmdBestellDetailsDELETE = new SqlCommand("BestellDetail_Delete", conn);
cmdBestellDetailsDELETE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefId", 35);

cmdBestellDetailsDELETE.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error:

> Procedure or function 'BestellDetail_Delete' expects parameter '@RefId', which was not supplied.

So could please anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing

```
  cmdBestellDetailsDELETE.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Without that flag the command type defaults to CommandType.Text and so it is expected to be something like "SELECT....", "DELETE...."

Comment: omg you are absolutely right  i look for nearly an hour at this ... in 11min i'm able to accept your answer